# EWR connecting from Terminal B to Terminal A (not on United)

Tags: ewr

Will pre-clear in Dublin so should come off in Terminal B as a domestic passenger. Need to get to Terminal A for outbound flight.

1) Can I use United shuttle bus at EWR if I'm not flying United? 
2) Any reason I'd need to go landside in this scenario?
3) Any concerns with making this in a 65min connection?

Thanks!

Comment: Which airlines are you flying?

Comment: Will you have bags?  Single ticket or multiple?

Comment: Coming in Aer Lingus, going out Alaska (gates 31/32)

Comment: One bag, carried on, multiple tickets

Answer (score 1):

You will absolutely have to go land-side.

Terminal A is basically 3 terminals in one - none of which are connected air-side.  The United shuttle goes only to the United part of the terminal where United (Express) flights depart from.  Given you've said you're not flying United, that'll obviously be the wrong part of the terminal.

The bus can also be somewhat unreliable, so you'll be best to avoid it entirely. From terminal B you will need to go airside, catch the free [AirTrain](https://www.airport-ewr.com/airtrain.php) to terminal A, and then re-clear security in whichever of the security checkpoints leads to your gate.

Whether this is possible in 65 minutes will depend mainly on how busy security is at the time, and whether you have TSA PreCheck and/or priority at security.  At best, it's going to be tight.  If you've got checked bags and those bags are not able to to checked through to your final destination then I'd say it's impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Newark has a monorail system connecting the three passenger terminals. They run every three to five minutes during the day. There is no need for a shuttle bus.

Here's a link describing the AirTrain system: [AirTrain Newark](https://www.airport-ewr.com/airtrain.php) Note that the system is free within the airport. The fares they describe are if you're connecting on to passenger train connections.

Comment: The AirTrain is landside, though, which means re-clearing security.